# Placing div in the middle of empty portion of window using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

In my template I have fixed div at the left of the main wrapper div , In the remaining portion I want to place my another div box perfectly in the middle even on window re-size.

I got the current window-size with jquery:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(window).resize(function() {
       var my_window = $(window).width();
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="rightbox"></div>
<div id="leftbox"> </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#wrapper{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:green;}

#leftbox{
position:fixed;
width:100px;
height:100%;
top:0;left:0;
background:red;}


#rightbox{
position:fixed;
width:400px;
height:100px;
bottom:100px;
left:50px;
background:blue;}
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/NpeRZ/

Now I want to place `rightbox div` in the middle of the green screen for any screen-resolution, so I want flexible width for this `rightbox div`. How to get this using jquery to set rightbox always in the middle. As well according to jquery `my_window` value I want to set different margin-left and margin-right for rightbox div.

```
for my-window 1024px :margin-left = 100px,
for my-window 768px  :margin-left = 80px.
for my-window 640px  :margin-left = 60px.
for my-window 480px  :margin-left = 40px.
for my-window 240px  :margin-left = 20px.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the documentation for jQuery Position and Offset that help you find/set object coordinates? http://api.jquery.com/offset/, http://api.jquery.com/position/. Suggest looking at jQueryUI position too: http://jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: Ignore my previous comment - in a dev mindset rather than CSS one. I'll leave for the links though which are useful if you're shifting stuff programatically :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#rightbox{
position:fixed;
width:400px;
height:100px;
left: 100px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin: auto;
bottom:0px;
background:blue;
}
```

The left would be the size of of the left frame or div.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Jquery, just change the css of the right box to:

```
#rightbox{
position:fixed;
width:400px;
height:100px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-150px;    
top:50%;
margin-top:-50px;
background:blue;}
```

Just tried it, works perfectly.

Comment: But I want it for responsive design so I want flexible width. width:400px is only for demo

Comment: Then, here is how i got the numbers: left:50% is always this, margin-left will be -200px (because the width of it is 400px, therefore half) but since the width of the left is 100px, we have to add half of its width to the distance therefore -200+50=-150px; top is always 50%, margin top is half of the height of the right, 100/2=50 therefore -50px;